# Correct usage of "spl-token transfer" with offline signing

Tags: signing, spl-token-cli, offline-tx

### Relevant info...

```
Source wallet: HcHQwif8dUB5MPg8miYsqw9YdoDmvpEZK7bnnUyyB5iG
Source USDC token address: C62nBdh3tfE9bQTSqTe2tq4oEQqAMqSeWgFY4aJpiEjp
Destination wallet: 5CaHcyQoT7v7Ma3ZL3xo7HqLv7mmYGTN9svZ9UXYgGqn
```

#### Solana CLI versions

```
# macos 14.3.1/Sonoma
> spl-token --version
spl-token-cli 3.3.0
> solana --version
solana-cli 1.17.24 (src:00000000; feat:3580551090, client:SolanaLabs)
```

### Problem

I've been testing USDC transfers between two test wallets using `spl-token`, and have been trying to do offline signing based on what I can glean from the help message.

I tried an online transaction on `devnet` and managed to get this command to run. I see `1 USDC` in the destination wallet after this transaction clears.

```
spl-token transfer 4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU  1 5CaHcyQoT7v7Ma3ZL3xo7HqLv7mmYGTN9svZ9UXYgGqn \
-u d \
--fee-payer fee-payer.json \
--from C62nBdh3tfE9bQTSqTe2tq4oEQqAMqSeWgFY4aJpiEjp \
--owner HcHQwif8dUB5MPg8miYsqw9YdoDmvpEZK7bnnUyyB5iG \
--multisig-signer fee-payer.json \
--allow-unfunded-recipient --fund-recipient
```

When I attempt to do an offline transaction using `--sign-only`, I get messages like `Error: AccountNotFound`, like here:

```
spl-token transfer 4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU 1 5CaHcyQoT7v7Ma3ZL3xo7HqLv7mmYGTN9svZ9UXYgGqn \
--fee-payer fee-payer.json \
--owner HcHQwif8dUB5MPg8miYsqw9YdoDmvpEZK7bnnUyyB5iG \
--from C62nBdh3tfE9bQTSqTe2tq4oEQqAMqSeWgFY4aJpiEjp \
--sign-only \
--mint-decimals 6 \
--blockhash 6oUffmsuZnvtxYBEtoBoKqow9NBqKvqMSMUgPoyCPyaD

# Error: AccountNotFound
```

Or if I specify `--multisig-signer`, same problem.

```
spl-token transfer 4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU  1 5CaHcyQoT7v7Ma3ZL3xo7HqLv7mmYGTN9svZ9UXYgGqn \
--from C62nBdh3tfE9bQTSqTe2tq4oEQqAMqSeWgFY4aJpiEjp \
--owner HcHQwif8dUB5MPg8miYsqw9YdoDmvpEZK7bnnUyyB5iG \
--sign-only \
--blockhash EULNnrujS48R85zMDGGpwRT938kgvmdBrJBzKJ4rS8v9 \
--mint-decimals 6 \
--fee-payer fee-payer.json \
--multisig-signer fee-payer.json

# Error: AccountNotFound
```

What is the account that's not being found, or what is the actual issue I'm running into? Running with `--verbose` flag doesn't show anything more, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the spl-token CLI.

There's always a weird intersection in the features of "offline signing" and "nonce signing". It's often assumed that they're being used together, so there's often inconsistencies in specifying one without the other, even though they're valid cases.

Since you've specified `--sign-only` but not `--nonce-authority` and `--nonce`, you're in the no man's land of "not well supported". Ideally, only specifying `--sign-only` would allow you to generate a signature for the transaction on the blockhash you've provided, but that doesn't always work.

Anyway, you can get around this by passing the `--transfer-hook-account` argument:

```
spl-token transfer 4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU  1 5CaHcyQoT7v7Ma3ZL3xo7HqLv7mmYGTN9svZ9UXYgGqn \
--from C62nBdh3tfE9bQTSqTe2tq4oEQqAMqSeWgFY4aJpiEjp \
--owner HcHQwif8dUB5MPg8miYsqw9YdoDmvpEZK7bnnUyyB5iG \
--sign-only \
--blockhash EULNnrujS48R85zMDGGpwRT938kgvmdBrJBzKJ4rS8v9 \
--mint-decimals 6 \
--fee-payer fee-payer.json \
--multisig-signer fee-payer.json \
--transfer-hook-account
```

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/6387 will fix this behavior